# php: how to swap letters with the mask regexp

Tags: php, regex

In word that begin with consonants cluster or consonant I need to put consonants (cluster) at the end of the word using regexp.

For example: `bbber-> er-bbb`, `bert->ert-b`, `avokado->avokado`

```
//if word begins with consonant letter
if (preg_match("/\b[b-df-hj-np-tv-xz]/i", $word)) {
            return preg_replace(??????);
        }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `preg_replace`:

```
$repl = preg_replace('/^([b-df-hj-np-tv-xz]+)([a-z]+)$/i', '$2-$1', $input);
```

[RegEx Demo](https://regex101.com/r/GxZzze/1)

**RegEx Breakup:**

- `^`: Start
- `([b-df-hj-np-tv-xz]+)`: Match and group starting block of consonants
- `([a-z]+)`: Match and group rest of the letters
- `$`: End

**Replacement** is `$2-$1` that basically changes the order of letters in original string.

Comment: How to add `qu` in this example? eg: `question->estion-qu`

Comment: Then you can use this regex: `/^(qu|[b-df-hj-np-tv-xz]+)([a-z]+)$/`